# Flipping graphics object without using G2D?

Tags: java, graphics, flip

Say I have a shape that I have drawn through paintComponent(), fillRect, or drawOval,

How would I go about flipping it, so that the shape would not be going from the top left, but from the bottom upwards?

Comment: The secret answer is... Math!

Comment: Simple answer: make the height negative. Although you would have to do this for everything you render

Comment: Alright thanks I'll try some things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was use the height of my panel, and subtract it from the height of the object.

for ex:

```
    int height = (1000 - n);
```

where n is the height that you wish the shape to be.